I got a problem when implement the backward function for Softmax Layer but I try many ways and still didn't. Can someone help me fix it?
I have the exercise for implement the Softmax function for forward and backward pass but when I run it, it have the bug like this:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  A row can only be accessed on an expression with exact two dimensions
Aborted (core dumped)

and here is my code and I was asked to use xtensor library to implement. I try to fix but it didnt work:
class Softmax {
public:
    Softmax(int axis) : m_nAxis(axis) {}

    xt::xarray<double> forward(xt::xarray<double> X) {
       
        cached_Y = softmax(X, m_nAxis);
        return cached_Y;
    }

    xt::xarray<double> backward(const xt::xarray<double>& DY) {
               
        xt::xarray<double> DX = xt::zeros<double>(DY.shape());
        int nclasses = DY.shape()[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < nclasses; i++) {
            xt::xarray<double> y = xt::row(cached_Y, i);
            xt::xarray<double> dy_i = xt::row(DY, i);
            xt::xarray<double> J = xt::diag(y) - xt::linalg::outer(y, y);
            xt::view(DX, i) = xt::linalg::dot(J, dy_i);
        }

        return DX;
    }

private:
    int m_nAxis;
    xt::xarray<double> cached_Y;

    int positive_index(int idx, int size) {
        if (idx < 0) return idx + size;
        return idx;
    }

    xt::xarray<double> softmax(xt::xarray<double> X, int axis) {
        xt::svector<unsigned long> shape = X.shape();
        axis = positive_index(axis, shape.size());
        shape[axis] = 1;

        xt::xarray<double> Xmax = xt::amax(X, {axis});
        X = xt::exp(X - Xmax.reshape(shape));
        xt::xarray<double> SX = xt::sum(X, {axis});
        SX = SX.reshape(shape);
        X = X / SX;

        return X;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    xt::xarray<double> X = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << "Input X: " << X << std::endl;

    Softmax softmax_layer(0);
    xt::xarray<double> Y = softmax_layer.forward(X);
    std::cout << "Softmax Output Y: " << Y << std::endl;

    xt::xarray<double> DY = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
    std::cout << "Input DY: " << DY << std::endl;

    xt::xarray<double> DX = softmax_layer.backward(DY);
    std::cout << "Backward Output DX: " << DX << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

I dont know why it can't access when calling the backward function.

IDK but it seems reasonably clear. The error is telling you that you can only access a row on a 2D array. But here xt::row(cached_Y, i); the variable cached_Y is clearly a 1D array (it's the 1D array you return from softmax).

In your forward pass, you're correctly going for a general softmax that receives the axis along which softmax should be computed in the constructor. In your backward pass, you're forgetting that and requiring both that softmax is always along axis 1 and that not just the input array, but also the general output of forward() will be 2D. Those are unnecessary assumptions since your sample arrays are valid inputs for a general softmax.
Doesn't help that nclasses is a misnomer, softmax is independently iterating not over the softmax axis - the number of classes - but over everything else.
You should reuse the variable m_nAxis and compute backward() along it, i.e. iterating over all views/slices with size shape()[m_nAxis] instead of all rows. From documentation, it seems xaxis_slice_iterator is what you need.
Also, if you're making any specific assumptions (you shouldn't here, just generally), you need to make sure they're either properly documented or validated in your code, ideally both. It'd help with debugging if you printed an error at the start of backward() saying that some array isn't 2D but needs to be. If this is an exercise you should turn in, it'd also look more impressive.
